# how to get CPU utilization in zabbix from Windows server?

Tags: windows, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I'm trying to monitor CPU utilization of windows 7 32bit PC (C2D E8400) using zabbix.
I tried both "perf_counter[\Processor Information(_Total)\% Processor Time]" and "system.cpu.util[,system,avg5]". After some time status of these items reverted itself to "Unsupported".

Is this problem on agent side, or at server? How to fix it? Ideally I want to see percentages load per each core.

UPD: topic and description updated.

UPD2: these counters work, but their value are float, and not decimal as I thought.

Comment: even the item `system.cpu.util[,system,avg5]` is possible for linux and windows machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPU load (what you have) is not the same as CPU utilization (what you're trying to get).  Load is a measurement of the average number of processes waiting on the processor(s), whilst utilization is the amount of time the processor was doing work during a given time snapshot.  You probably want to look at the counter:

```
perf_counter[\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time]
```

It's been a while since I've used zabbix, so syntax might have changed.

Comment: yes, you are right, it called utilization

Comment: for the record, you can get a list of available perfcounters by issuing something like : typeperf -qx > performance_counters.txt; 

windows specific parameter syntax can be seen in the zabbix manual at http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/config/items#win32-specific_parameters

Comment: Hey hi @Jon Angliss i got the cpu utilization using above items but do you know to get  cpu utilization of particular process. I already try perf_counter[\Processor(<processname>)\% Processor Time] but its not working please help with this

Comment: @Mohit Jain; this should probably be asked as a separate question but the notes Richlv left should find you the answer to what you want.

Answer (score 4):

I just added the items and triggers for:

```
 system.cpu.util[,,avg1]

 system.cpu.util[,,avg5]

 system.cpu.util[,,avg15]
```

It is working in Zabbix Agent 2.0.4 and Windows 2008. Because have differences between CPU Load and CPU Utilization.